# Pointer to function parameter vs function parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'd like to understand what is the difference between the 2 declarations, `f1` and `f2`, below:
In `f1` I declare the parameter to be a pointer to a function of type `void()`, how is the `f2` declaration different from the `f1`? Are the declarations equivalent? In `main` I can invoke both of them with functions of prototype `void ()`. I understand the concept of passing by value/pointer/reference, however these are functions and don't really understand the difference. It is not like I can "modify" the function passed as parameter in `f1`... Thanks!

PS: came by this question when bumping into the well known Most Vexing Parsing problem :)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f1(void (*x)())
{
    x();
}

void f2(void x())
{
    x();
}

void g1()
{
    cout << "Invoking f1(g1())" << endl;
}

void g2()
{
    cout << "Invoking f2(g2())" << endl;
}


int main() 
{
    f1(g1);
    f2(g2);
}
```

The program compiles and the output is

```
Invoking f1(g1())
Invoking f2(g2())
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're equivalent.  You're getting confused by the implicit pointer conversion that happens with arguments.

Since you can't pass a function as an argument to a function (you can't do anything with functions in C other than call them or take their address), the compiler silently changes the argument into a pointer to a function.

This is much the same as happens with arrays -- you can't pass arrays as function arguments either, so any time you declare a function argument as an array, it silently gets changed into a pointer.

Comment: Ok, thanks, knew that's what was happening with arrays, however didn't know about the function stuff. Many thanks, will accept your answer as it was marginally faster :)

Answer (score 13):

In both C and C++, if you declare a function parameter to have function type, its type will be adjusted to function pointer.

C99, §6.7.5.3/8

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘function returning type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘pointer to
>              function returning type’’, as in 6.3.2.1.

C++11, §8.3.5/5

> ... After
>   determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is
>   adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively...

Thus, in C++, for example, we can write the types of both `f1` and `f2` as `void(void(*)())`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the significant paragraph from the standard!

Answer (score 2):

They are alternative syntax for the exact same thing. In both cases a function pointer is passed, but you are allowed to use non-pointer syntax in the parameter list.  Use of a function name always decays to a pointer to function (and this can happen recursively).